# R-package beeswarm generates same x-coordinates

Tags: r, plot, distribution, swarmplot, beeswarm

I am working on a script where I need to calculate the coordinates for a beeswarm plot without immediately plotting. When I use beeswarm, I get x-coordinates that aren't swarmed, and more or less the same value:
[image]

But if I generate the same plot again it swarms correctly:
[image]

And if I use `dev.off()` I again get no swarming:

[image]

The code I used:

```
n <- 250
df = data.frame(x = floor(runif(n, 0, 5)),
                y = rnorm(n = n, mean = 500, sd = 100))

#Plot 1:
A = with(df, beeswarm(y ~ x, do.plot = F))
plot(x = A$x, y=A$y)

#Plot 2:
A = with(df, beeswarm(y ~ x, do.plot = F))
plot(x = A$x, y=A$y)

dev.off()

#Plot 3:
A = with(df, beeswarm(y ~ x, do.plot = F))
plot(x = A$x, y=A$y)
```

It seems to me like beeswarm uses something like the current plot parameters (or however it is called) to do the swarming and therefore chokes when a plot isn't showing. I have tried to play around with beeswarm parameters such as spacing, breaks, corral, corralWidth, priority, and xlim, but it does not make a difference. FYI: If `do.plot` is set to TRUE the x-coordinates are calculated correctly, but this is not helpful as I don't want to plot immediately.

Any tips or comments are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right; beeswarm uses the current plot parameters to calculate the amount of space to leave between points.  It seems that setting "do.plot=FALSE" does not do what one would expect, and I'm not sure why I included this parameter.

If you want to control the parameters manually, you could use the functions `swarmx` or `swarmy` instead. These functions must be applied to each group separately, e.g.

```
dfsplitswarmed <- by(df, df$x, function(aa) swarmx(aa$x, aa$y, xsize = 0.075, ysize = 7.5, cex = 1, log = ""))

dfswarmed <- do.call(rbind, dfsplitswarmed)

plot(dfswarmed)
```

In this case, I set the xsize and ysize values based on what the function would default to for this particular data set.  If you can find a set of xsize/ysize values that work for your data, this approach might work for you.

Otherwise, perhaps a simpler approach would be to leave do.plot=TRUE, and then discard the plots.